# MySQL and Typed Dataset Designer slow

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, mysql-connector, msdatasetgenerator

This question concerns the use of Connector\Net, MySQL, and the visual studio integration of the typed data set designer. As a beginner I have almost entirely default settings, and am using InnoDB for tables.

It appears that on certain tables the designer slows to a grind on adding new queries to the adapter for me. Looking in the Workbench administrator it appears to be running through a loop of similar queries fetching the schema of the tables, checking permissions, deleting tmp tables, etc. I presume it is trying to validate the syntax of the query that I'm adding and get details to implement the XSD spec.

I am not sure how to proceed in debugging this further. The slowdown becomes essentially equivalent to a total freeze. If I had to take a total guess I'd say there's looping going on rather than a slow sequence of events. I'd say a timeout exception gets swallowed, and a loop repeats. If you shutdown the service, the logon creds dialogue will pop up in the designer but you can't cancel out of it without shutting down the VS process which seems sloppy.

Any ideas? Is this functionality being used by other people or am I in no man's land?